# unable to get Local Notifications

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

Unable to get local notifications

i have created notification channel, and its working properly,but when i try to execute showimmediatenotification()  i am able to get toasts in those blocks but notifications arent being showed up, firebase cloud notifications are running perfectly

further once local notifications are set up i want to fetch date from firebase Realtime db and set a notification on that dy, please help me in atleast one of the problem or both if persists

```
    private void showImmediateNotification() {
        // Example date string, replace with your actual date string
        String dateString = "2023-12-26T14:03:30Z";
        Toast.makeText(taskviewlist.this, "1718", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Retrieve the Date object from the TaskModel instance
        TaskModel taskModel = new TaskModel(/* pass relevant parameters here */);
        Date date = taskModel.convertStringToDate(dateString);

        // Check if the task's deadline is in the future
        if (date != null && date.after(new Date())) {
            String title = "Immediate Notification";
            String message = "This is an immediate notification.";

            // Call sendImmediateNotification with the context
            Toast.makeText(taskviewlist.this, "Showing Immediate Notification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            NotificationScheduler.sendImmediateNotification(taskviewlist.this, title, message);
        }
    }
```

```
    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "Your Notification Channel";
            String description = "Channel for your app notifications";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("7", name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            // Register the channel with the system
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            if (notificationManager != null) {


                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

                Log.d("Notification", "Channel created successfully"); // Add this log statement

            }
        }
    }
```

```
package com.example.ntasks;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Date;

public class NotificationScheduler {

    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 7;

    public static void scheduleNotification(Context context, Date notificationDate, String title, String message) {
        // Create an Intent to be triggered by the alarm
        Toast.makeText(context, "1166", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("title", title);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("message", message);

        // Create a PendingIntent for the Intent
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                NOTIFICATION_ID,
                notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
        );

        // Get the AlarmManager service
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        // Set the alarm to trigger at the specified time
        if (alarmManager != null) {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, notificationDate.getTime(), pendingIntent);
        }
    }

    public static void sendImmediateNotification(Context context, String title, String message) {
        try {
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Immediate Notification Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log the exception for debugging
            Log.e("NotificationScheduler", "Error sending immediate notification", e);}}}
```

```js
package com.example.ntasks;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;

public class NotificationHelper {

    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "taskrem";
    private static final String CHANNEL_NAME = "notif";
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    public static void showNotification(Context context, String title, String message) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            builder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
    }
}
```

```html
package com.example.ntasks;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.d("Notification", "Notification received!");
        String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

        // Handle the notification, for example, by displaying it
        NotificationHelper.showNotification(context, title, message);
    }
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-firebase-cloud-messaging-on-android-d92cb4b53cfe) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseCloudMessaging).